# Red dot in Web socket sent message, cannot copy what is it?

Tags: websocket

I'm looking in Chrome dev tools at a WS connections for a chat app and all sent messages have a red dot. I cannot copy the red dot, it is on the second line with new line active. Never seen this in a WS connection.

What is this red dot?

[image: red dot ws message]